# why is UI/Activity destroyed after onActivityResult

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to update the imageview on `onActivityResult` after I call up a camera intent but it seems like the view is getting destroyed and recreated after the onActivityResult.  It works fine if I do it on the onCreate.  I'm using a Galaxy S3 for testing.

Oddly it seems to have worked for a little while when I built the same code on my desktop, but not on my laptop.  After debugging it for a while the problem arose again in the desktop build as well and in the debugger the bitmap gets updated correctly in the onactivityresult but then the activity gets destroyed and created immediately again resetting the view to the initial state.

The onCreate is called three times, 1. when the screen first shows up, 2. after the camera intent is finished and before onActivityResult, and 3. after the on Activity Result.  I'm not sure why the activity gets destroyed and re-created before #2 and #3.

I'm not doing any orientation changes.

** Code **

Acvity settings in manifest

```
   android:configChanges="orientation"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String imageUri = "file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Funhouse/IMG_20130826_163938.jpg";

            // Try by using setImageURI
            preview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri));

        }
     }
```

The onCreate and Intent request

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_preview);

//      works fine if I set the image view here
//      String imageUri = "file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Funhouse/IMG_20130826_163938.jpg";
//      preview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri));
    }



    public void takePhoto(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }
```

Here is the layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn_take_photo"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
         android:onClick="takePhoto"
         android:text="Take Photo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error/crash do you get? Is there an error? or, it simply doesn't show the image in the ImageView?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't show the image in the image view

Comment: Are you sure that your imageview is at the screen in that moment? setBackground as BLUE or something and see if it's properly at layout

Comment: Yes I'm sure the imageview is on the screen since I can see the thumbnail placeholder image I am using on it initially and it's still on screen

Comment: In the onloadingcomplete of image loader function check if it is able to parse the URI and get valid Bitmap. I mean make sure Bitmap is not null

Comment: it's a valid bitmap, tested the same function call on oncreate and works fine, just not onActivityResult.  I've even just tried updating text on a button- which also doesn't work

Comment: Is the code inside `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { .... }` being executed? Can you confirm this with a `Log.i()` statement?

Comment: yes it is being executed, confirmed with log and debug break points

Comment: Odd... I just compiled it on a different machine and it seems to work... what could be causing the issue on my laptop builds but not on my desktop builds?

Comment: Do you test it in the emulator or real device. If on the emulator, does it have the same config : Same Android version, same GPU host, intel image etc ....

Comment: I tested on real device, Samsung Galaxy s3

Comment: looks like oncreate is being called again after the onactivity result which is why I'm guessing the ui gets reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out returning from the camera activity was calling the on destroy after the ui was updated in OnActivityResult, resetting the UI of the original calling activity.  The screen resolution change was being triggered by the Camera Activity returning, but only after the onActivityResult event.

Updating the android manifest to ignore screen resolution changes on that activity fixed it.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```