# Error in geting Image from Action_Image_Capture Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i am using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE fro capturing image from camera using Intent . 
i am using this code :

```
    Intent i = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //startActivity(i);
            startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

And getting the intent result through this code :

```
      InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        try
        {
            // recyle unused bitmaps
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

            imgPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR 2 :->",e.toString());
        }

            if (stream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("ERROR 3 :->",e.toString());
                }
            }

    }
```

But when i click tick button in picture preview intent then it gives me this error :

```
     1-10 00:55:34.675  25036-25036/com.digicare.digitrick W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e3d258)
       01-10 00:55:34.686  25036-25036/com.digicare.digitrick E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity
```

Where is i am missing some thing ????
how can i get the captured image in my ImageView ?

Comment: Can you post your entire onActivityResult?

Comment: Andro Selva this is entire code . just missing the start line .


       @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

Comment: then probably try calling super.onactivityResult() on the first line. That could help..

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your activity gets destroyed during the Camera activity operation and re-created afterwards because the Camera APP is heavy on resources.
You can try to rotate your activity to force your activity destroy and recreate to check the problem.

See this for more info~
[why is UI/Activity destroyed after onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453669/why-is-ui-activity-destroyed-after-onactivityresult)